# Debts I had long before becoming a Muslim

Tags: debt

Salam. Long before becoming an Islamic Muslim or even believing, I owed money but have since lost any contact with these people. I’m talking about 30 years ago. Now, while learning more and more about Islam, I’m now reading about debts. I’m terrified of being trapped in my grave cause I owed money. I do not work as I am disabled. My husband deserted me over 5 years ago and I run the home on my own. My 19 year old son is my caregiver and can not work. He also has ADHD. What shall I do about the debts?